RDLC textbox properties to currency
I have a textbox in RDLC. Now I want to change it into a currency format, but it does not work. The display value of my textbox looks like this: 2200, not like this: $ 2,200
IMAGE
I tried to change my textbox expression from this:
=First(Fields!total.Value, "DataSet1") 

IMAGE
to this:
=Format( First(Fields!total.Value, "DataSet1")  ,"0.00")

and not work for me

As an alternative, you could select the textbox and enter "$ #,##0.00" for the Format property. These format specifiers will transfer to excel when using excel rendering.

Good day  Ross Bush, I try to change the value of my textbox expression and still not working sir.

Use
=Format(First(Fields!total.Value, "DataSet1") , "C0")

You can also set the textbox properties:
Number ->  currency

